# python relational inclusive operators not inludind start and end values

Tags: python, relational-operators

The goal of the function is to output a value in a given range. Including the start and end value if it is entered as input. The function only outputs the expected result for values at the start and between the range.

```
def main():
    #assume user input will be formatted in 24-hour time as #:## or ##:## 
    time = input("What is the time: ")

    if time >= "7.0" and time <= "8.0":
        print("breakfast time")
    elif time >= "12.0" and time <= "13.0":
        print("lunch time")
    elif time >= "18.0" and time <= "19.0":
        print("dinner time")

def convert(time):
    h, m = time.split(":")
    time = float(((float(h) * (60)) + float(m)) / 60)
    return time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

- current output when input is i.e 8:00 --> ""
- expected output when input is i.e 8:00 --> breakfast

Comment: You are not using convert at all. And even if you use it after `time = input(...)` you will get type error because you will compare string to float

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need first to call you `convert` method, and change the conditions to avoid exception comparing `string` with `float`

```
def main():
    time = convert(input("What is the time: "))

    if time >= 7.0 and time <= 8.0:
        print("breakfast time")
    elif time >= 12.0 and time <= 13.0:
        print("lunch time")
    elif time >= 18.0 and time <= 19.0:
        print("dinner time")

def convert(time):
    h, m = time.split(":")
    time = float((int(h) * (60) + int(m)) / 60)
    return time

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There is also a reason to cast `h` and `m` to int instead as there can't be 1.5:30.5 time

Comment: @SWEEPY just started out with python, still figuring out when and were to call a given function. I've been at this function for a few days now..thanks for pointing these points out.

Comment: @sudden_appearance part of the assignment requirement is to convert time to a decimal, hence the .5, not sure why it is required as it does not appear to play a particular role in the solution to the function, however, its required to have the functions assessed as a pass.

Comment: @sandramsc it depends on your situation, check this out [Working with functions in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.11/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions)

Answer (score 0):

Use `datetime.strptime` to parse text representations of times, then compare them to other `time` values.

```
from datetime import datetime, time


def main():
    #assume user input will be formatted in 24-hour time as #:## or ##:## 
    current_time = input("What is the time: ")
    
    current_time = datettime.strptime(current_time, "%H:%M").time()

    if time(7) <= now <= time(8):
        print("breakfast time")
    elif time(12) <= now <= time(13):
        print("lunch time")
    elif time(18) <= now <= time(19):
        print("dinner time")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```